# Subquery filter sum with one to many in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have 2 entities:

```
@Entity
class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Contract> contracts= new HashSet<>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
class Contract {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private Integer numberOfClaims;
}
```

Now I want to build a `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate` to find all Orders with `numberOfClaims` greater then x.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: I don´t remember all the code I tried, but here are the general ideas I had in mind: 
a) select * from order o where sum(o.contracts.numberOfClaims) > x 
b) Some queries with "having" instead of "where", but i hadn´t success with that approach
c) Using a subselect

Comment: I used hibernate to create my db tables. It created a match-table "order_contract" for my 2 entities. I can use this select ```SELECT *
FROM order o
WHERE ( ( SELECT SUM(numberOfClaims)
            FROM order_contract oc
            LEFT JOIN contract c
            ON  c.id = oc.contract_id
            WHERE o.id=oc.order_id ) >= :x) ``` to get the right result, but i don´t know how to build this select with jpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select o from Order o where
(select sum(c.numberOfClaims) from o.contracts c) > x
```

See some correlated subquery examples in the following cmobilecom-jpa developer guide:

https://cmobilecom.com/docs/jpa/latest/devguide/index.html

Using Criteria API:

(refer to the section: "Correlate To Root" of chapter "Subquery")

```
CriteriaQuery<Order> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Order.class);
Root<Order> root = criteriaQuery.from(Order.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root);
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);

// Subquery: correlate the root of parent query
Subquery<Integer> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<Order> subqueryRoot = subquery.correlate(root);
Join<Order, Contract> contracts = subqueryRoot.join("contracts");
subquery.select(criteriaBuilder.sum(contracts.get("numberOfClaims")));

Predicate restriction = criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(subquery, x);
criteriaQuery.where(restriction);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the query and got the right results. I also had a look at the guide, but I'm still having trouble transforming  the query into a predicate (using ```Root<Order>, CriteryQuery and CriteriaBuilder```). Could you please help me?

Comment: Added criteria API for subquery. hope it helps.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much